# trouble updating to mysql inside reader loop

Tags: c#, mysql

I am looping through these mysql rows and processing data.  But, in part of the processing I am also wanting to update into the same mysql table.

This is not working for me.

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE outbox SET `faxpro` = 'DONE' WHERE `id` = '" + id + "'";
                MySqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();
```

CODE

```
    string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=communications;Uid=myuser;password=mypass;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM outbox WHERE `faxstat` = 'Y' AND `fax` <> '' AND `faxpro` = 'PENDING'";


        try
        {

            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
               Console.WriteLine(reader["account"].ToString());
                SendFax(reader["filepath"].ToString(), reader["filepath"].ToString(), reader["id"].ToString(), reader["fax"].ToString());
                string id = reader["id"].ToString();
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE outbox SET `faxpro` = 'DONE' WHERE `id` = '" + id + "'";
                MySqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();

            }
        }
```

Comment: What does *"This is not working for me"* mean? Btw, you should not only nest the `conn.Open();` in a `Try-Catch` but above all `command.ExecuteReader();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that last command.ExecuteReader() tries to open one more reader, but it is not possible to do with one connection. Close first open reader firstly, then modify this table; or try to use command.ExecuteNonQuery() method.

Comment: Thanks.  I added a second connection and used it for the updating.

Comment: Also, find information about SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement, it might be helpful for you task.